# Reference to pointer issue

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a question regarding references to pointers, or a pointer reference or whatever you want to call it, but first some code. First, an abstract compare function template class:

```
template <class T> struct BinaryTrivalent {
    virtual BinaryTrivalent<T>* clone() const = 0;
    virtual int operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) const = 0;
    int compare(const int a, const int b) const {
        if (a < b)
            return LESS_THAN;
        else if(a == b)
            return MATCH;
        return MORE_THAN;
    }
};
```

And the actual use of it:

```
struct NodePCompare : public BinaryTrivalent<Node*> {
    NodePCompare* clone() const { return new NodePCompare(*this); }
    int operator()(const Node*& lhs, const Node*& rhs) const {
        return compare(lhs, rhs);
    }
};
```

The template works fine on actual types but it doesn't seem to recognise `operator` as I expect it to and tells me that `NodePCompare` is abstract.
I've come across this problem in the past but I gave up trying to figure out what the problem was and just wrapped the pointer in another type.
I could do the same thing now but I would like to understand what the real issue is.
I've been reading up on what exactly `*&` is supposed to mean in this context and, unless I haven't understood correctly, this *should* work fine.
This link helped a bit in understanding it: http://markgodwin.blogspot.co.il/2009/08/c-reference-to-pointer.html

Ideas anyone?

Comment: well, `operator ()` in `NodePCompare` should be `virtual`

Comment: It's implicitly virtual, you can add `virtual` keyword just to remember it yourself but it is not needed by the compiler.

Comment: @Jack: right, forgot that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the signature doesn't really match.

It should be this:

```
int operator()(Node* const & lhs, Node* const & rhs) const {
    return compare(lhs, rhs);
}
```

The problem is where the `const` ends up applying. You could accomplish the same thing by saying `typedef Node * base_T_arg_t;` in the private section of your class and then saying this:

```
int operator()(const base_T_arg_t &lhs, const base_T_arg_t &rhs) const {
    return compare(lhs, rhs);
}
```

Basically, the `const` before the `*` doesn't bind to the type of the pointer as a whole, it binds to the type `Node`.

The return type of `clone` is a red herring for two reasons. First, a function signature does not include its return type. So you are most definitely creating a definition of `clone` that matches the original signature and will therefore override it.

But, if your return types didn't match the compiler would normally give you an error. Except there's a principle called '[contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)' that allows return types that are references or pointers to be references or pointers to a derived class when the function is overridden.

After all, a pointer to a derived type is freely convertible to a pointer to a base type. They're, in a sense, equivalent.

Comment: First of all, thank you! I think that did it! :)
Second: well it seems you've answered it before I had a chance to add this comment so thanks again :)

Comment: As for the "red herring": should I just have left it out of the question or were you explaining that I'm not doing something right there? I mean, I did mention that `operator()` was the problem and not `clone()`.

Comment: @itchy23: You're doing just fine there. I only put that in because of the other answer that was deleted. That person was confused and I wanted to explain why their answer was wrong in a nice way. But the fact they initially gave that answer does mean any other random person coming along might decide that was the issue as well, and so the explanation would probably help them too. Besides, contravariance is a neat concept, and it's not widely known. So, there's that reason for explaining it too.

Comment: Yes true, I was about to comment on the same thing but the answer disappeared before I could do that. Thanks again